Formatting Laravel collection based on related data
I have a simple array that contains the data I need but needs to be formatted a little differently:
It is currently 1 collection that holds an array of collections. However, I need to merge certain data points if they exists.

    [0] => [
        'name' => 'Test 1 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0001',
            'zone' => 'blue'
        ],
        'name' => 'Test 2 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0002',
            'zone' => 'red'
        ],
        'name' => 'Test 3 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0003',
            'zone' => 'yellow'
        ],
        'name' => 'Test 4 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0004',
            'zone' => 'black'
        ],
        'name' => 'Test 5 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0001',
            'zone' => 'green'
        ],
    ]


As you can see the first district array and the last district array have the same district but different zones.
When that happens I need them to be merged into an array with the first district it finds that's similar and remove the other.
Wanting these results on a collection dump:

    [0] => [
        'name' => 'Test 1 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0001',
            'zone' => [
                'blue',
                'green'
            ]
        ],
        'name' => 'Test 2 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0002',
            'zone' => 'red'
        ],
        'name' => 'Test 3 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0003',
            'zone' => 'yellow'
        ],
        'name' => 'Test 4 Name',
        'districts' => [
            'district' => '0004',
            'zone' => 'black'
        ]
    ]

The name does not play a part in this and doesn't matter. Added for basic data point.

so name Test 5 Name will be removed since its district is the same with Test 1 Name then zone becomes an array from string?

To start with, you would need to group name and district as an array or object. Right now, each name and district represents an element of initial array like [1, 2, 3, etc] .
